# What is meant by "constant" in the optional stopping theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

One of the three condition of the optional stopping theorem is that "[There exists a constant $c$ such that $|X_{t\wedge \tau}| \leq c$ a.s. for all $t\in \mathbb N_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem)".

In [the article of Wikipedia on the optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem#Applications), the second item in the linked section gives an example of an application of the theorem:

> Suppose a random walk starting at $a \geq 0$ that goes up or down by one
>   with equal probability on each step. Suppose further that the walk
>   stops if it reaches 0 or $m \geq a$; the time at which this first occurs is
>   a stopping time. If it is known that the expected time at which the
>   walk ends is finite (say, from Markov chain theory), the optional
>   stopping theorem predicts that the expected stop position is equal to
>   the initial position a. Solving $a = pm + (1 – p)0$ for the probability
>   p that the walk reaches m before 0 gives $p = \frac am$.

Since once the random walk is defined the number $m$ is a fixed integer, could also the condition (c) there be applied? That is, it is true that there exist a "constant" that bounds the absolute value of the martingale?

Another example (third item of the linked section), gives me even more doubt:

> Care must be taken, however, to ensure that one of the conditions of
>   the theorem hold. For example, suppose the last example ["a random walk $X$ that starts at 0 and stops if it reaches $–m$ or $+m$"] had instead
>   used a 'one-sided' stopping time, so that stopping only occurred at
>   $+m$, not at $−m$. The value of $X$ at this stopping time would therefore be m. Therefore, the expectation value $E[X_{\tau}]$ must also be $m$, seemingly in
>   violation of the theorem which would give $E[X_{\tau}] = 0$. The failure of
>   the optional stopping theorem shows that all three conditions fail.

It seems to me that in the latter example the real problem is that the "one-sided" stopping time is not indeed a stopping time: it can be infinite. On the other hand, if it were a stopping time, it does not seem to me that "all three conditions fail" because $|X_{\tau}|\leq m$ for a **fixed** $m$. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first:  yes, you could also use part (c) there, because the stopped process is always bounded by $m$ in absolute value.

For the second: stopping times **are** allowed to be infinite!  However, the thing you are missing here is due to a shortfall in Wikipedia's explanation of their example: when they refer to the one-sided stopping time, they mean that the ONLY stopping condition is reaching $m$... so, for instance, you could go to $-10,000,000$, then work your way back.  So, in this case, the stopped process isn't bounded - it is only bounded above.

Comment: Thank you! I did not encounter that definition of stopping time before (I'm in the "some cases" of the Wikipedia definition  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time#Definition).

Comment: Is the optional stopping theorem still true with a definition of stopping time that allows it to be infinite? I think no: let the random walk stop moving as it reaches $m$ or $-m$, but define the stopping time to be the time it reaches $m$; this stopping time is infinite but if we could use part (c) we got a contradiction.

Comment: Well, if you note, the optional stopping theorem specifically requires something like "the stopping time is bounded almost surely" or "$\mathbb{E}[T]<\infty$", or some such other condition; these all imply that it is finite almost surely.